# write key and values from map to a file

Tags: java, iteration

With the code below, I am trying to write the key and values of the male and female map to an existing file.

But it shows the following error.

Can somebody help me please.

```
   ERROR@      Map.Entry entry = (Map.Entry) entryIter.next();

   java.util.NoSuchElementException
   at java.util.LinkedHashMap$LinkedHashIterator.nextEntry(Unknown Source)
   at java.util.LinkedHashMap$EntryIterator.next(Unknown Source)
   at java.util.LinkedHashMap$EntryIterator.next(Unknown Source)
   at test.main(test.java:83)
```

Code

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Map<String, List<String>> MaleMap = new LinkedHashMap<String, List<String>>();
    Map<String, List<String>> FemaleMap = new LinkedHashMap<String, List<String>>();
    try {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new FileReader(".txt"));

        while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
            String nextLine = scanner.nextLine();
            String[] column = nextLine.split(":");
            if (column[0].equals("Male") && (column.length == 4)) {
                MaleMap.put(column[1],
                        Arrays.asList(column[2], column[3]));
            } else if (column[0].equals("Female") && (column.length == 4)) {
                FemaleMap.put(column[1],
                        Arrays.asList(column[2], column[3]));
            }
        }
        Set<Entry<String, List<String>>> entries = MaleMap.entrySet();
        Iterator<Entry<String, List<String>>> entryIter = entries.iterator();
        while (entryIter.hasNext()) {
            Map.Entry entry = (Map.Entry) entryIter.next();
            Object key = entry.getKey(); // Get the key from the entry.

            List<String> value = (List<String>) entry.getValue();
            Object value1 = " ";
            Object value2 = " ";
            int counter = 0;
            for (Object listItem : (List) value) {
                Writer writer = null;
                Object maleName = key;
                Object maleAge = null;
                Object maleID = null;
                if (counter == 0) {// first pass assign value to value1
                    value1 = listItem;
                    counter++;// increment for next pass
                } else if (counter == 1) {// second pass assign value to value2
                    value2 = listItem;
                    counter++;// so we dont keep re-assigning listItem for further iterations
                }
            }
            System.out.println(key + ":" + value1 + "," + value2);
            scanner.close();
            Writer writer = null;
            Object maleName = key;
            Object maleAge = value1;
            Object maleID = value2;
            try {
                String filename = ".txt";
                FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(filename, true); // the true will append the new data
                fw.write(maleAge + "." + maleID + "@@;" + "\n"
                        + " :class :" + maleName);// appends the string to the file
                fw.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
        Set<Entry<String, List<String>>> Fentries = FemaleMap.entrySet();
        Iterator<Entry<String, List<String>>> FentryIter = Fentries.iterator();
        while (FentryIter.hasNext()) {
            Map.Entry entry = (Map.Entry) entryIter.next();
            Object Fkey = entry.getKey(); // Get the key from the entry.

            List<String> value = (List<String>) entry.getValue();
            Object value1 = " ";
            Object value2 = " ";
            int counter = 0;
            for (Object listItem : (List) value) {
                Writer writer = null;
                Object femaleName = Fkey;
                Object femaleAge = null;
                Object femaleID = null;
                if (counter == 0) {// first pass assign value to value1
                    value1 = listItem;
                    counter++;// increment for next pass
                } else if (counter == 1) {// second pass assign value to value2
                    value2 = listItem;
                    counter++;// so we dont keep re-assigning listItem for further iterations
                }
            }
            System.out.println(Fkey + ":" + value1 + "," + value2);
            scanner.close();
            Writer writer = null;
            Object femaleName = Fkey;
            Object femaleAge = value1;
            Object femaleID = value2;
            try {
                String filename = ".txt";
                FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(filename, true); // the true will append the new data
                fw.write("map:" + femaleName + " a :Bridge;" + "\n"
                        + ":property" + femaleAge + ";" + "\n"
                        + ":column" + " " + femaleID + " " + ";");// appends the string to the file
                fw.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`Map.Entry entry = (Map.Entry) entryIter.next();` in your second loop is breaking.

After the first while loop that iterates through the males, your iterator has reached the end of the set, and will break when you try to call `next()`.

What you actually want to do is iterate through your females.

Change the line to iterate with your `FentryIter`:

```
while (FentryIter.hasNext()) {
   Map.Entry entry = (Map.Entry) FentryIter.next();
```

This is most likely the result of copy-paste code, and you need to be careful when doing this. I would recommend re-factoring your code since so much of it is duplicated.